# How to make changes to database(sqlite) after first migration in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django development and I'm currently following a tutorial to make a blog app. During the tutorial, there is a step to create a function to allow new user use `deafult.jpg` as their avatar.

However, I had a typo there. Instead of typing `'default.jpg'`, I typed `'default.jpb'`.

Then I migrated into the database. Therefore, when I run the server and try it out, new users who have not set their avatar is using `"default.jpb"` instead of `"default.jpg"`.

Now, how can I change the database to use the right definition?

After I found the problem, I corrected my typo in my model and then used the following command:

```py
python3 manage.py makemigrations (no changes detected)
python3 manage.py migrate (no migrations to apply)
```

then, I decided to delete the migrations in my project then makemigrations again, and I realized that I couldn't make changes that already inside my database.

```py
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    # Create your models here.

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',     upload_to='profile_pics')

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I expect new users who have not set their avatar is using default.jpg that located in my project.

Comment: Have you tried to make migrations again after deleting the migration files?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention in my post, and I did try to make migrations again. yet I couldn't change the value that already inside my database.

Comment: Make sure you have an `__init__.py` file in your `migrations` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you deleted the migrations files.  This means when you run `makemigrations` again it will have name it as `001...`.  BUT the database will still have a record of migrating that file in `django_migrations`.

Either undelete the deleted migrations and run makemigrations then migrate OR edit your database and remove the migrations that you've deleted from `django_migrations`

Answer (score 0):

run python3 manage.py makemigrations profile and then run python3 manage.py migrate this will solve the issue